# What is last step in installation of Tcl/Tk on Ubuntu 15

Tags: software-installation, python

On Ubuntu 15.* I did a `sudo apt-get install tk8.5 tcl8.5` and that ran fine.

But, when I start Python and `import tkinter` I get an error message:

```
ImportError: no module named "_tkinter"
```

I assume I have one more step like changing my `$PATH` or something else. 
Can't seem to find what that might be - new to Linux.

Please advise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Python module `tkinter` is provided by the packages `python-tk` (for Python 2) and `python3-tk` (for Python 3). Just install one of them (or both).

Comment: Your advise looks good -BUT- I did a sudo apt-get install python3-tk THEN started python3 - THEN  did import tkinter -AND- got the following error message:  File “/usr/local/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py”, ;in 38, in <module> import _tkinter # If this fails your Python may not be configured for Tk - ImportError: No module named ‘_tkinter’ - Not sure how to configure Python - in point of fact, didn’t know one could configure Python - Any advise is welcome.  Geez

Comment: @Amanda `File "/usr/**local**/lib/python3.4/tkinter/__init__.py"`. The correct path should be `/usr/lib/python3.4/tkinter/..`. Did you mess with Python or (re)install it from source or something? Try starting Python by calling `/usr/bin/python3.4`.

Comment: Oh geez that is exactly what I did, i.e., a reinstall after a failed install from sources AND I knew I messed up something.  I just ran ./python3.4 from directory /usr/bin And it worked - no errors with importing tkinter - thanks - I’m going to be using PyCharm as my IDE and I believe I can set that dir in the run configuration of PyCharm - So I think I’m good now. Great Thanks.